# Which Eclipse Version for Android that Runs on Embedded

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse

I am basically an Embedded guy, worked mostly on C/C++ languages. One of my projects requires an Android application that runs on any Android based Mobile phones and controls my embedded system hardware which is basically a Raspberry Pi 2 through WiFi.

I am new to Android development and I need inputs from experts on how to proceed with the basic tools installation and development.

I found lots of Eclipse versions available, which made me bit confused. 
Do I need to download Eclipse IDE for Java Developers or Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developer. Which version and which category do I need to use for Android application development?

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boj0f_O3i88) for reference.

Comment: Google is dropping Eclipse support at the end of the year. You are better served examining IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, both of which are supported by Google, at least for the Android portion of your project.

Comment: Recommend downloading the Java version and then installing the CDT into it. See here: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

You only need one version of Eclispe IDE, you can install CDT plugins to allow you code in other languages with the same IDE.

CDT: [CDT Downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

Detailed Instructions: [How To](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html)